# Get S3 bucket free space in Ceph cluster from amazon S3 API

Tags: amazon-s3, ceph

Is exists any way to get available free space in Ceph cluster from amazon S3 API?
I need to implement automatic deletion of outdated objects from bucket when Ceph cluster has no space to store new objects. I know exists ways to calculate used space in bucket, but its logic data size and I can't compare them to raw size of cluster disks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From S3 perspective you can't check free space.

Ceph has implemented expiration mechanism, which will delete outdated objects from your object storage.
Check the doc: http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/s3/#features-support

Comment: Thanks. Ceph expiration mechanism is not solution for my problem, I need to implement complicated expiration logic like quotas etc. Will search another solution (not S3 and not Ceph) for this task.